# git stash apply not retrieving all the files

Tags: git

I was working on stuff. I had to stash it to work on something quickly. Now I want to recover the stuff I was working on. So I run git stash list which gives me this:

```
stash@{0}: WIP on developers: 044f243 fixing some bugs since address resource
```

So I run `git stash apply stash@{0}`. I thought it would bring back all of the files, but it only brought back SOME of the files. When I run git stash list again, I still see the following:

```
stash@{0}: WIP on developers: 044f243 fixing some bugs since address resource
```

If I run `git stash apply stash@{0}` again, then I get the following error:

```
error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge:
```

I just want to bring back all of the files I was working on before I ran git stash. How do I do that?

Comment: What was your original stash command?  Did you have stages changes and modified files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely your confusion is caused by the following facts about `git stash`

- `git stash` stores only changes, it doesn't store new files
- `git stash apply` applies specified revision, but keeps your stash on the
  stack. To apply stash and remove it from the stack you may use `git stash pop`
- you may re-apply stashed changes multiple times

You may find all the stashed changes with `git stash show stash@{0}`.

Comment: So how can you retrieve untracked files after a stash?

Comment: @DanStayntouch if you stashed them, then you can get them back with `git stash pop` (or `apply`, if you will). Otherwise, they will remain unstaged after `git stash` and their future is in your hands.

Comment: if the changes are listed in the stash, i expect them to be applied. Whats confusing about that?